# MAAS add virtual node - 'namedtuple_as_object' error

Tags: server, python, juju, maas

I have a KVM-based virtual machine up and running on a server that's also running MAAS. I'm following the instructions here: http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/nodes.html#virtual-machine-nodes to add the VM to MAAS, so I've added in the relevant fields (`Address`, `Power ID` & `MAC address`) I get the following 500 error:

`Unable to create Node: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namedtuple_as_object'`

The stack trace from `/var/log/maas/maas.log` is:

```
ERROR 2014-02-10 17:20:55,312 maasserver ################################ Exception: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namedtuple_as_object' ################################
ERROR 2014-02-10 17:20:55,313 maasserver Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py", line 19, in inner_func
response = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 201, in __call__
else: stream = srl.render(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/emitters.py", line 391, in render
seria = simplejson.dumps(self.construct(), cls=DateTimeAwareJSONEncoder, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 296, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namedtuple_as_object'
```

I'm not a Python person, so not sure what's going on in the above, but I have found this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-django-piston/+bug/1184871 mentioning Python, Django & Piston, all of which appear in the above stack trace.

Do I need to update one of the above packages? `sudo apt-get update` says everything's fine.

Running `Ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal` on the metal itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bug mentions a fix was released for the *python-django-piston* package, try running:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

If the package gets upgraded, restart *maasserver* and retry adding the VM.